# How to position a picture by its corner

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm new with LaTeX and Tikz.

I would like to include a picture on my document by positionning its north west corner on the north west corner of my page.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \begin{scope}[shift={(current page.north west)}]
        \draw (0,0) node {\includegraphics[scale=.07]{./figures/logo.jpg}};    
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I wrote this but it includes the center of my picture on the coordonate (0,0). I don't know what I have to add to have what I would like to have.

How can I do that, please ?

Comment: you also need to shift the handle of your node via `\node[anchor=north west] {\include.....}`

Comment: It's the parameter I was looking for. Thanks a lot to you and to the community. =)

Comment: To avoid inner margin, use `inner sep=0`...

Comment: @percusse Do you want to write up an answer, or do you know of a duplicate?

Comment: Link to similar question, but with two corners specified:  [Loading a graphics image in Tikz given the position of the bottom side? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641493/loading-a-graphics-image-in-tikz-given-the-position-of-the-bottom-side)

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to use the logo on many pages, it might be worth using `background` which has a nice key-value interface for this kind of thing.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background,kantlipsum}
\backgroundsetup{%
  contents={\fbox{\includegraphics{tiger}}},
  scale=.175,
  position=current page.north west,
  nodeanchor=north west,
  opacity=1,
  angle=0,
  color=orange,
}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image: tigers on top]