# Loading a graphics image in Tikz given the position of the bottom side?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, rotating, scaling

Is it possible to write a Latex macro based on \includegraphics so that given two points A and B this will become the lower side of the image (i.e., the image will be translated, scaled, and rotated accordingly)? This would give a functionality equivalent to that provided by Geogebra. It should have 3 arguments - the two pints and the image file name.

Answer (score 1):

With `sloped` TikZ option you can already go a long way: (*read the notes in the code to understand what it does*)

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,fp}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
... (copy code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38500/250119 and paste here)
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path   % specify the corner points.
        (2, 3) coordinate (b)
        (4, 5) coordinate (a)
        ;

    \calcLength(a,b){mylen}  % store the distance between 2 points into mylen.
    % DO NOT include a space e.g. between a and b

    \path
        (a) to node [midway, sloped, allow upside down, above, inner sep=0] {
            \includegraphics[width=\mylen pt]{a.png}
        } (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

the remaining part is to compute the distance between two nodes and pass it to the width of includegraphics.

It's the reader's exercise on how to wrap the functionality into a macro.

---

<sub>alternative question title (for searching): How can I include an image in TikZ with corners anchored at two points?</sub>

Comment: Link to similar question [tikz pgf - Draw a square with given points - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563420/draw-a-square-with-given-points)

Comment: Similar question without rotating the node: [positioning - TikZ: position with different anchors - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31299/tikz-position-with-different-anchors)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is in the right direction, but there is a problem with the scaling. The image lays on the segment connecting a with b but is smaller than it should be.  I think that in order to get the right dimensions we should use some rounding too.  Do you have a good documentation of loadgraphics?  (BTW, package pretty  is missing in overleaf and seems to be superfluous)

Comment: @bandi (yes, personal debug package, forgot to remove.)

Comment: @bandi texdoc graphicx page 9, or LaTeX unofficial reference manual (latex2e.pdf) page 201.